# how to send search suggestion data to searchable activity using action bar search widget?

Tags: android

My search is working using action bar search widget. Now I want to filter my search result according to the input from the activity which invokes the search. I don't know how to send extra data to searchable activity. I need some help please ?

Comment: Have you already gone through this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html?

Comment: Ya.. It's not there or maybe I couldn't find

Comment: So is your question, how to send a search phrase to an activity?

Comment: No. it's there and working perfect, according to activity state I want to filter my results

Comment: I am using this same activity for 6 different category products, so if i search something it should return only that particular type of results

Answer (score 0):

In your intent, add the data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("filter", filter);
startActivity(intent)
```

Then read the data in your search activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String filter = intent.getStringExtra("filter");
```

Comment: This is useless. I'm using action bar search widget